# trouble aligning the divs and other inner tags at different positions

Tags: html, css

I'm creating my first ever html page, and I'm trying to do some alignment for divs and labels. 
The labels and the input seem out of position even after spending multiple hours trying different combinations. Some properties are not working, like I used width for label and in chrome it says unknown property.

Below is the code. Any help with this would be appreciated.

---

**Preview of the html/css part:**

```css
div.btn-toolbar {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  left: 40%;
  width: 400px;
}

div.quote-details {
  position: relative;
  top: 122px;
  left: 250px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
}

div.quote-detail-section-left {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 145px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  width: 35%;
}

input.quote-input {
  padding: 4px;
}

label.field-label {
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40px;
  width: :50px;
  clear: both;
}

div.quote-detail-section-right {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 145px;
  margin-right: 80px;
  width: 35%;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote-rec-page">
  <div class="quote-details">
    <label for="section" class="Segment">Quote Details</label>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-toolbar">
    <button type="button">Edit</button>
    <button type="button">Delete</button>
    <button type="button">Create PDF</button>
    <button type="button">Email Quote</button>
    <button type="button">Start Sync</button>
  </div>
  <form>
    <div class="quote-detail-section-left">
      <div>
        <label for="quoteNum" class="field-label">Quote Number</label>
        <input type="text" class="quote-input" tabindex="1" id="quoteNumber" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="quoteName" class="field-label">Quote Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="quote-input" tabindex="2" id="quoteName" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="oppName" class="field-label">Opportunity Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="quote-input" tabindex="3" id="oppName" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="accName" class="field-label">Account Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="quote-input" tabindex="4" id="accName" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="quote-detail-section-right">
      <div>
        <label for="expDate" class="field-label">Expiration Date</label>
        <input type="date" class="quote-input" tabindex="5" id="expDate" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="sync" class="field-label">Syncing</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="quote-input" tabindex="6" id="sync" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="status" class="field-label">Status</label>
        <input type="text" class="quote-input" tabindex="7" id="status" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="quoteDesc" class="field-label">Description</label>
        <input type="text" class="quote-input" tabindex="8" id="quoteDesc" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

---

**Html/css including apex code:**

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false">
    <head>
        <title>Quote Details</title>
    </head>
    <style>
        div.btn-toolbar{
          position:relative;
          top:100px;
          left:40%;
          width:400px;
        }
        div.quote-details{
          position:relative;
          top:122px;
          left:250px;
          font-weight:bold;
          font-size:15px;
        }
        div.quote-detail-section-left{
          float:left;
          margin-top : 145px;
          margin-left: 100px;
          width:35%;
        }
        input.quote-input{
          padding:4px;
        }
        label.field-label{
          float:left;
          font-weight:bold;
          display:inline-block;
          margin-left : 40px;
          width::50px;
          clear:both;
        }
        div.quote-detail-section-right{
          float:right;
          margin-top : 145px;
          margin-right: 80px;
          width:35%;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="quote-rec-page">
            <div class = "quote-details">
                <label for = "section" class="Segment">Quote Details</label>    
            </div>
            <div class ="btn-toolbar">
                <button type="button">Edit</button>
                <button type="button">Delete</button>
                <button type="button">Create PDF</button>
                <button type="button">Email Quote</button>
                <button type="button">Start Sync</button>
            </div>
            <form>
                <div class ="quote-detail-section-left">
                    <div>
                        <label for="quoteNum" class ="field-label">Quote Number</label>
                        <input type="text" class="quote-input"  tabindex="1" id="quoteNumber"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="quoteName" class ="field-label">Quote Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="quote-input"  tabindex="2" id="quoteName"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="oppName" class ="field-label">Opportunity Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="quote-input"  tabindex="3" id="oppName"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="accName" class ="field-label">Account Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="quote-input"  tabindex="4" id="accName"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class ="quote-detail-section-right">
                    <div>
                        <label for="expDate" class ="field-label">Expiration Date</label>
                        <input type="date" class="quote-input"  tabindex="5" id="expDate"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="sync" class ="field-label">Syncing</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="quote-input"  tabindex="6" id="sync"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="status" class ="field-label">Status</label>
                        <input type="text" class="quote-input"  tabindex="7" id="status"/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label for="quoteDesc" class ="field-label">Description</label>
                        <input type="text" class="quote-input"  tabindex="8" id="quoteDesc"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: what do you want it to look like?

Comment: What does the apex:page tag do? What framework is this? Also, you have errors: <style> shouldn't be between the <head> and the <body>; some of the `for` attributes in the labels don't point to existing inputs; and there's a double colon in one of the width properties, probably causing the error you see in Chrome.